# TypeError at /app/profile/ , 'list' object is not callable handle_pageBegin args=()

Tags: python, django, pdf, unicode, django-views

I want a button to create a PDF file (with Python 2.7, Django 1.8), but I have no clue how to express that to the machine.

I started by reading some articles, trying to learn from the others how could that be done.

Found [this handy link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/08/how-to-export-to-pdf.html), which  redirected me to the following links:

- [ReportLab on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/)

So, in order to print as PDF:

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\**Method one: using [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)** /////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
pip install reportlab
```

ReportLab relies on *Pillow*, which is a third-party Python Image Library.
If you run:

```
pip install Pillow
```

You'll see something like this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\pythonprojects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\pythonprojects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages (from Pillow)
```

Nothing else seems to be needed at this level, so let's start by making sure we have everything we need in the view.

------------------------------------------**Version 0.2** (code was wrong)------------------------------------------

***1.*** Code

```
# views.py
from django.http import response
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
import requests
import praw


def profile(request):
        #PDF
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf")
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        Story = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]
        style = styles["Normal"]

        #Webpage
        parsedData = []
        userData = {}
        if request.method == 'POST':
        #Data
            sub = request.POST.get('subreddit')
            reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='client_id',
                                 client_secret='client_secret',
                                 user_agent='user_agent')
            # assuming you have a Reddit instance bound to variable `reddit`
            subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)

            print('Master, this was the data retrieved that is going to be displayed:')
            print(subreddit.display_name)  # Output: redditdev
            print(subreddit.title)  # Output: reddit Development
            print(subreddit.description)  # Output: A subreddit for discussion of ...
            print('Tell me if you want more and I can give that to you, no problem-------------')

         #PDF
            print('Now, Im gonna create a PDF file with the same data...')
            subreddit_name = subreddit.display_name
            subreddit_title = subreddit.title
            subreddit_description = subreddit.description

            p = Paragraph(subreddit_name, subreddit_title, subreddit_description,  style)
            Story.append(p)
            Story.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
            doc.build(Story)
            print('The file was created and can be accessed in the root of the Django project. The name is test.pdf')
            print('Tell me to stop if you dont like what Im doing-------------')        

        #Webpage
            print('OK. Time to give that to the user as well...')
            userData['subreddit_name'] = subreddit.display_name
            userData['title'] = subreddit.title
            userData['description'] = subreddit.description
        parsedData.append(userData)
        return render(request, 'app/profile.html', {'data': parsedData})
```

From the moment the code under `#PDF` was inserted, the view was never the same.

***2.*** Errors

*Traceback as image:*
[image]

*Traceback as text:*

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/profile/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('frontend',
 'app',
 'blog',
 'suit',
 'suit_redactor',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\PythonProjects\reddit_development\demonstration\app\views.py" in profile
  69.         doc.build(Story)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in build
  1213.         BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in build
  969.                     self.handle_flowable(flowables)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in handle_flowable
  834.             if frame.add(f, canv, trySplit=self.allowSplitting):
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\frames.py" in _add
  167.                 w, h = flowable.wrap(aW, h)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\paragraph.py" in wrap
  1191.         leftIndent = style.leftIndent

Exception Type: AttributeError at /app/profile/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'leftIndent'
```

***3.*** Where I think is the problem?:

**The code runs fine, until this part:**

```
p = Paragraph(subreddit_name, subreddit_title, subreddit_description,  style)
Story.append(p)
Story.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
doc.build(Story)
```

------------------------------------------**Version 0.3** ----------------------------------------------

Accordingly to [Christoph Bluoss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7222529/christoph-bluoss) in his message and to [the documentation](http://svn.cern.ch/guest/lhcb/packages/tags/L0/L0mPy/v4r1/doc/html/reportlab.platypus.paragraph.html),

```
p = Paragraph("Some string", style)
```

Knowing this,

***1.*** Code

*a. Created 3 classes*

```
Story1 = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]

Story2 = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]

Story3 = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]
```

*b. Created 3 new variables*

```
p1 = Paragraph(subreddit_name,  style)

p2 = Paragraph(subreddit_title, style)

p3 = Paragraph(subreddit_description, style)
```

c. Appended all of the variables in a different class each

```
Story1.append(p1)
Story1.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))

Story2.append(p2)
Story2.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))

Story3.append(p3)
Story3.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
```

d. Did a doc.buil with those variables.

```
doc.build(Story1, Story2, Story3)
```

***2.*** Errors

*Traceback as image:*
[image]

*Traceback as text:*

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/profile/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('frontend',
 'app',
 'blog',
 'suit',
 'suit_redactor',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\PythonProjects\reddit_development\demonstration\app\views.py" in profile
  77.         doc.build(Story1, Story2, Story3)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in build
  1213.         BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in build
  966.                 self.clean_hanging()
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in clean_hanging
  554.             self.handle_flowable(self._hanging)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in handle_flowable
  828.             f.apply(self)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in apply
  153.             annotateException("\nhandle_%s args=%s"%(action,ascii(args)))
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\lib\utils.py" in annotateException
  1390.     rl_reraise(t,v,b)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in apply
  146.             getattr(doc,arn)(*args)
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in handle_pageBegin
  1189.         self._handle_pageBegin()
File "C:\PythonProjects\virtualenvs\apis\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py" in handle_pageBegin
  579.         self.pageTemplate.onPage(self.canv,self)

Exception Type: TypeError at /app/profile/
Exception Value: 'list' object is not callable
handle_pageBegin args=()
```

***3.*** Where I think is the problem:

**The code runs fine, until this part:**

```
 p1 = Paragraph(subreddit_name,  style)
 p2 = Paragraph(subreddit_title, style)
 p3 = Paragraph(subreddit_description, style)
 Story1.append(p1)
 Story1.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
 Story2.append(p2)
 Story2.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
 Story3.append(p3)
 Story3.append(Spacer(1, 0.2 * inch))
 doc.build(Story1, Story2, Story3)
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\**Method two: using [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)** /////////////////////////////////////////////////

If we can't fix with the past method, this seems like a good deal.

Comment: Would you mind to post the django traceback as text instead of the image?

Comment: look now @ChristophBluoss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to your updated problem (v 0.3)
According to the documentation http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf (page 68):

> BaseDocTemplate.build(self, flowables, filename=None, canvasmaker=canvas.Canvas)
>
> Assuming that the document instance is correctly set up the build
>   method takes the story in the shape of the list of flowables (the
>   flowables argument) and loops through the list forcing the flowables
>   one at a time through the formatting machinery

While you on the other hand just called build() with a couple of lists instead. Actually, I don't even get why you're using 3 seperate lists at all and not just **a single list** like this in the first place.

```
story = [Spacer(1, 2 * inch)]
story.append(Paragraph(subreddit_name,  style))
story.append(Spacer(1, 2 * inch))
story.append(Paragraph(subreddit_title, style))
story.append(Spacer(1, 2 * inch))
story.append(Paragraph(subreddit_description, style))
doc.build(story)
```

which is working fine. (tested with python3 though)

Comment: tested in pyton 2.7.12

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the Paragraph() documentation](http://svn.cern.ch/guest/lhcb/packages/tags/L0/L0mPy/v4r1/doc/html/reportlab.platypus.paragraph.html), the 2nd argument is the paragraph style. You're providing the subreddit_title instead, which is a regular unicode string and did not work.

Your code should look like this:

```
p = Paragraph("Some string", style)
```

And just my 2cents at the topic of pdf generation.
I found http://weasyprint.org/ much more convenient to work with. Reportlab w/o a license is quite laborious to work with.

Comment: http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html looks cool though, gonna have a proper look